# Как формат файла exo перевести в mp4?

Tags: расширения, формат

В приложении кинопоиска можно скачивать фильмы, как можно эти куски перевести в обычный формат mp4? Вот так выглядит одна серия сериала
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что внутри данных папок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вам нужно для личного пользования, то воспользуйтесь онлайн конвертором: [онлайн конвертор](https://onlineconvertfree.com/ru/convert-format/exo-to-mp4/)